# Content of div should be at their initial position after mouse remove

Tags: javascript

Here it is a code pen [URL](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emPzyK). I want content at the initial position after mouse remove from `<div>` Rather than one single `<div>` I have 6 different `<div>` 3 in one row. The transform should be same on every `<div>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Style Attr

```
 $(".card").on("mouseleave",function(e) {
  card.removeAttr('style')
});
```

[LINK](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNqobL)

Answer (score 0):

Tried an animated reverting on mouse leave.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raQWLO?editors=110

```js
// why it doesn't work on firefox?
var card = $(".card");

$(".card").on("mousemove",function(e) {  
  var ax = -($(window).innerWidth()/2- e.pageX)/20;
  var ay = ($(window).innerHeight()/2- e.pageY)/10;
  card.attr("style", "transform: rotateY("+ax+"deg) rotateX("+ay+"deg);-webkit-transform: rotateY("+ax+"deg) rotateX("+ay+"deg);-moz-transform: rotateY("+ax+"deg) rotateX("+ay+"deg)");
});

$(".card").on("mouseleave",function(e) {
    card.attr("style", "transform: rotateY("+0+"deg) rotateX("+0+"deg);-webkit-transform: rotateY("+0+"deg) rotateX("+0+"deg);-moz-transform: rotateY("+0+"deg) rotateX("+0+"deg);-webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;-moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;-o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;transition: all .5s ease-in-out;");
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400italic,700);

body{
  background: #edf2f4;
  perspective: 1000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Playfair Display",georgia,serif;
}
.card{
  //pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  padding: 30px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  
  //position: relative;
  
  &:after{
    content:" ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left:0;
    bottom:-50px;
    box-shadow: 0 30px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    
  }
  
  .card-content{
    margin: auto;
    text-align:center;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  
  h1{
    transform: translateZ(100px);
  }
  p{
    transform: translateZ(50px);
    display: block;
    
    &.related{
      transform: translateZ(80px);
      font-style: italic;
    }
  }
  a{
    color:#69c6b8;
    pointer-events: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-content">
    <h1>Just hover around</h1>
    <p><small>by <a href="http://ariona.net" target="_blank">Ariona, Rian</a></small></p>
    <p class="related"><strong>See also: </strong><a href="http://codepen.io/ariona/pen/LEEadb" target="_blank">Animated highlight text</a></p>
    
  </div>
</div>
```